# How do I squash the latest commit into HEAD^2

Tags: git

Here's the `git log` (added the numbers for easier reference):

```
4. * 0fa18b8 - (HEAD -> master) Update readme (2 seconds ago) <resting>
3. * dd5ca5c - Add file (60 seconds ago) <resting>
2. * 0abc586 - update readme (7 minutes ago) <resting>
1. * f85b4d8 - initial commit (8 minutes ago) <resting>
```

`4` and `2` changes the same file and I want to `squash` them together, leaving `3` as the latest.

End result should look something like this:

```
3. * dd5ca5c - (HEAD -> master) Add file (60 seconds ago) <resting>
2. * 0abc586 - update readme (7 minutes ago) <resting>
1. * f85b4d8 - initial commit (8 minutes ago) <resting>
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

`git rebase -i f85b4d8` (one commit **before** `2`)

Edit the commits:

```
pick 0abc586 update readme
fixup 0fa18b8 update readme
pick dd5ca5c Add file
```

Exit and save.

Comment: Note that when you are done, the two commits you have atop `f85b4d8` will be *new* (different) commits, and not have any of these three hash IDs. The original three commits will still be in your repository: they are merely hidden, so that you don't *see* them. Eventually (in no less than 30 days by default) Git will garbage-collect these commits if you do not do anything to restore them.